Why "mute your microphone" when it doesn't make sounds?
Why do we 'mute' a microphone? It listens, it doesn't make sounds. It would be like muting your ears. Shouldn't it be 'deaf' your microphone?
If that sounds too strange, there is the old standby: "turn off", which is what my software says the camera does. Aren't off and on sufficient? 'Mute' is a bit of an anthropomorphism anyway.
Here's a suggestion: block. You block things from coming in: calls, video, sounds, chat messages, rain, sun... Use block to stop unwanted things coming to you, don't try to control the other person or their stuff.

Well, you can mute a trumpet. And you can ask English for consistency. At least the trumpet will be quieter.

Mute doesn't mean the same as turn off, at least with a powered mic. And isn't deaf a bigger anthropomorphism?

Check out this usage chart. turned off the microphone is still the dominant form, but muted is making a strong showing over just the last couple of decades. And it's gaining traction faster in the more informal context of mic rather than microphone, which is probably significant.

Mute your mike = put your mike on the "mute" setting. In what way does this modern usage conflict with the dictionary definition of the verb "mute"? Please edit your question to include evidence of the supposed conflict in usage.

A mute person is someone who can't speak. A deaf person is someone who can't hear. So do microphones hear, or speak? If you want to not see someone's video,  you don't say, "dim your eyes".

@ChappoHasn'tForgotten but why is it called the "mute" setting?  My dictionary says that the mute setting makes a device (for example, a television) silent.  As the question says, microphones don't normally make sounds.

This sense of 'mute' is likely a result of semantic extension from earlier usages of the same sense and also from the earlier sense "to deaden or to muffle sound of a person or thing". Similar to how we mute other electronic devices like TVs or stereos, phones and microphones also have a 'mute' function and additionally a 'mute' button. When we say 'mute your microphone,' it can be considered a form of metonymy also because muting the microphone mutes your voice. Generally, 'mute' in this context means to turn off the sound transmission and 'muting' is often temporary unlike 'turning off'.

Even if we as a culture had picked a different word for it, you still wouldn't "deaf" your microphone, you'd deafen it.  Though that sort of implies that you would blast it with decibels until it actually broke.  Rock and roll!

I am glad they closed the Question and not my keyboard. At least they didn't try to dim my camera.

A microphone doesn't just listen, it also typically transmits whatever it picks up somewhere else. It's not uncommon for a muted mic to still be able to hear you when muted, it just doesn't transmit the audio anywhere else. A muted mic is not deaf - some videoconferencing programs show a reminder if you try to speak while muted, which they obviously couldn't do if muting the mic prevented it from detecting sound.

Further proof, if we needed more, that 'mute' is absolutely inappropriate to the situation. Maybe we could say to stop transmitting sound, like we say to stop sending video? Stop is an all-purpose word. If we use computer terms too loosely, the results could be pear-shaped, like those old iMacs.

We use the verb 'dust' to mean 'sprinkle with powder' and 'remove dust from'. These extensions happen; when they're established, it almost always makes less sense to object than to go with the flow.

@EdwinAshworth right, if your vacuum cleaner really sucks, does that mean it works well, or...? Sometimes words acquire a secondary meaning that dissuades people from the original use, such as that word for happy.

But 'mute a microphone' is now an established usage; 'block a microphone' isn't. ELU only countenances established usages.

@EdwinAshworth ok! Watch for "dim your camera", I'm going to establish it!

Individuals like Shakespeare, Milton, Blake, Becket, Tolkien and Rowling are more likely than laypersons to come up with new usages that become accepted.

The transitive verb to mute [something] (a television, for example) is to make something silent.  Microphones, especially on telephones, have a "mute" setting because they make you silent (along with every other noise being picked up by the microphone): not in an absolute sense, but to the intended recipient of the transmission (the person at the other end of the line, the auditorium, the recording device).
Once mute was established as the name for setting on the microphone that prevents it from transmitting sound, it's a short step to the verb phrase mute your microphone, meaning "activate the microphone's mute function."

So we would dim the phone's camera too, I guess. Turn off wasn't adequate? You could block someone from a chat by untyping their keyboard. Hey, block seems ok for preventing input from coming through, doesn't it? We block callers, we don't hang them up.

@TinyPhone "block" means something different from "hang up on," which people certainly do say.  "Turn off" is perfectly adequate, but it implies a complete disabling rather than a temporary partial disabling.  So in the context of, e.g. a television remote control or a chat interface, it's "mute."  There's a semantic shift here; I'm describing the logic behind it.  Unfortunately for people who are bothered by semantic shifts (often including me, but not in this case), fighting against them is a losing battle.

Muting something that actually produces sound is fine. In terms of transmitting, radios used to have push-to-talk buttons, which would be raging great for conference calls and so on, where it is assumed that one person isn't going to hog the mic the whole duration. PTT, anyone? An idea whose time has returned?

The best why possible to provide is that meanings of words often shift and grow with time and that’s simply how language works.
In this case, the semantic progression is quite reasonable. We start with an idea like “I wish not to be heard. I wish that the sounds of my speech—and perhaps of my surroundings—should not be picked up, as though they had not been produced at all. As if I—and perhaps my surroundings—were mute.” From this, it’s reasonable to label (in the sense of conceiving of) a switch on an audio-capture device with some description like “Arrange matters as though I and my surroundings were mute.” Obviously, a description that long would never be literally, physically applied. But its single-word kernel, mute, serves nicely.
While your semantic objection (that the only valid patients of an action of muting are those things that are capable of the original production of sounds) does have logic to it, it’s a brand of logic to which language never has fully conformed and never will. In this sense, the objection is parallel to a (hypothetical) complaint that a sentence like

Fortunately, the rain stopped five minutes before the start of the ceremony

is nonsensical because only sentient entities are capable of caring about the weather, so rain cannot have luck, either good or bad. Indeed, one could justify this complaint by pointing out that the word fortunate comes from the Latin passive participle meaning caused [by something] to prosper, as in Claudia Pulchra has been caused [by the gods?] to prosper. But obviously, we have extended the use of fortunate to refer not only to those entities capable of experiencing luck, but also now to those things that trigger the experience of good luck.
[And note that a few cranks would likewise object to my previous sentence’s obviously. “It is not the case that we have extended in an obvious manner,” they would gripe, “so you should have used it is obvious that instead.”]

Don't get me started on jealousy and envy.

My goal is to clarify technical terms. Getting them right can be crucial. There is actually a long history of people saying that language use is deteriorating. Perhaps we should heed these folks rather than simply yielding to sloth and disorderliness.

For every example you can cite of a language's becoming "slothful," there are examples of its becoming more demanding. For every example of increasing disorder there are examples of increasing regularity. And any feature you can hold up as particularly admirable, someone from that long history you mention would have decried it as a novelty that threatened the beauty of whatever standard he was peddling.

And you're taking to a mathematician, so I know well the importance of careful and precise definitions... in certain contexts. You are, of course, welcome to use language as you wish it to be, but if you also wish to be understood and accepted, then you might want to cede some ground to how language actually is used by others.
